# How to get Custom Property from ASP.NET Textbox using javascript?

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I have created a custom text box with property "key"(ASP.NET C#).I want to get the value of this property "key" using java script.How can I do this?

Comment: don't post your question as the title.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you are asking.

if you have a textbox rendered like so:

```
<input type="text" id="foo" key="somekey" text="Hello" />
```

You could get the value of "key" in JS like so:

```
document.getElementById('foo').getAttribute('key')
```

Comment: I have created a server side custom control 
<cus:TextBox id="foo" Key="somekey" runat="server" Text="Hello"/>

I want to get the value of key.

In view source Html generated is <input type="text" id="foo"  text="Hello" />
No Html is generated for custom property Key.

Comment: If key is not generated in the html, then you have a problem with your custom control.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery than for this will help you.

```
$("#tb1").attr("key")
```

for this textbox

```
<input type="text" id="tb1" key="mykey" text="" />
```